# How to apply CSS only if class exists elsewhere in code?

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

So I'd like to only apply a certain CSS if a class exists in the code elsewhere. I was wondering if this is solely possible through css or if I need to use Jquery for this. Do anyone has any thoughts on this? If I need to use Jquery, can you give an example on how that might looks like?

As you can see in my code, what I try to do is apply a `margin-top` when `li.active` exists.

Obviously my jsfiddle is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/zt40oa7d/

Or see the code below:

```css
div.navbar {
  background-color: #CCF;
}
ul.box {
  margin: 0;
}
div.text {
  background-color: #FFC;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.page div.navbar ul.box li.active div.text {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="box">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="text">This the div that should go down due to the submenu ul</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div.page div.navbar ul.box li.active div.text` - I don't think this is possible with pure CSS because `div.text` is neither a sibling or a descendant/child of `li.active`.

Comment: _"I'd like to only apply a certain CSS if a class exists in the code elsewhere"_ -- Please be more specific.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "apply a certain CSS if a class exists in the code elsewhere", using the code in the question as an example

Comment: I updated my topic: As you can see in my code, what i try to do is apply a margin-top when li.active exists.

Comment: What you need is a javascript function which will cycle through your elements, searching for the specified class and apply the other class if something is found.

Comment: @Andi, ok thanks. Any examples/best practices on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its very possible to do this, its called the addClass() method in JQuery and it is used like this

```
$( "div" ).addClass( "text" );
```

Which in turns adds this CSS to your element

```
.text
{
   background-color: #FFC;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

this will produce the effect shown in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rv10c39y/)

You can also remove it using `$( "div" ).removeClass( "text" );`

**EDIT**

You could also check if the active class exists using the hasClass() method in JQuery like this:

```
if( $("li").hasClass( "active" ) )
{
  $( "#specificDiv" ).addClass( "text" );
}
```

And your HTML with updates

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="box">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="specificDiv">This the div that should go down due to the submenu ul</div>
</div>
```

Here you are checking if the `<li>` has the class "active" assigned to it. If it does it will set the css "text" on the element which contains the id "specificID" but wont affect any other divs.

Have a look at what this does [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rv10c39y/2/)

Read more on the JQuery addClass() method [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp).

Read more on the JQuery hasClass() method [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_hasclass.asp).

Comment: Thank you. However it does not seem to be working? see http://jsfiddle.net/rv10c39y/ i deleted the predefined class text.. and the jquery wont add any class... Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Did the trick for me! What is better though; use filter or add class?

Comment: It really depends on how the rest of your application will work. If you think that you will have another class that might use similar logic then by all means carry on using the add class method but if not its best to filter out elements that you do not want inheriting this style. I hope that makes sense if not im more than happy to help further :)

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery, you can find the length of li element with class `.active` on document ready, if yes then set the css to div with class `.text`:

```
$(function(){
if($('.active').length){
     $('div.text').css(' margin-top',' 100px');
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLr2u94/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to apply rules to a *certain* div when a *certain* `li > a` has been clicked... You can do this **CSS only**

[image: cssonly]

```
.text {
    display: none;
    background-color:#FFC;
    padding:10px;
}
.text:target {
    display:block;
}
#text1 {
    background: #bada55;
}
#text2 {
    background: #639;
}
#text3 {
    background: tomato;
}
```

html

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul class="box">
            <li><a href="#text1">Test dropdown 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#text2">Test dropdown 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#text3">Test dropdown 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="text1" class="text">
        <h1>Foo</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima aspernatur qui excepturi quas non tempore deserunt neque eos ducimus nobis tempora nam beatae aliquam necessitatibus aliquid accusantium vel libero cumque!
    </div>
    <div id="text2" class="text">
        <h1>Bar</h1>This the div that should go down due to the submenu ul
    </div>
    <div id="text3" class="text">
        <h1>Baz</h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus impedit quam cum. Sit quaerat architecto maiores veritatis labore minus dolorem earum sint sapiente est pariatur accusamus ducimus dolore sunt ipsa!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't really see how to apply your solution to my problem though.. Can you please further elaborate? Thank You!

Comment: so using this, you don't need to add the `toggleClass()`. this just applies styles to the active (href=#text1,2,3) dropdown's respective div (#text1,2,3).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Check if ul tag children() which is li has '.active' class or not. If it does have then set the attr as active of the id '#textdiv' as bellow:

Write this (add id in your 'active' class):

```
<div id="textdiv" class="text">div text</div>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var a = $("ul.box").children('li').hasClass('active');

   if (a == true) {
     alert("asdf");
     $("#text").attr("class","text");
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Looks like something i need. however how does that look in fiddle? Cant seem to make it work for some reason. See: http://jsfiddle.net/xvy2tcv6/

Comment: See my edited answer. `hasClass()` return true is certain div has particular class.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('.box li').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        // add your margin-top here
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! how do i make it add any class or margin? Can you maybe show me on a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Milind Anantwar's answer using jQuery.

However I would be more specific with my if.

```
$('.active')
```

Will return any element with the class active

```
$('li.active')
```

Will return li elements with the class active

```
if ($('li.active').length) { ... }
```