# jquery - check, if .class is present & and then automatically add .class to specific #id on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conditional-statements

jquery - check, if .class is present on site or at specific #id and then add .class to specific #id

hey folks,

I know, there are many topics (30586451, 27947009, ...) regarding a similar issue, but i tried at least 15 code snippets in js and jQuery and none of them seem to work for me whereas other scripts just work fine on the same page.

I am currently coding a static site using Hugo server and no matter, what i try, i can't get a necessary .class to automatically get added to a certain  #id. This should happen only if another .class is present on the current visible siteelements. The page is a one page which dynamically shows and hides content based on navigation without reloading but different anchors get pushed into the url (also tried listening to that but no avail). It is put together from .md, .toml and .html bits.

I can see the trigger class in the src code (tried in html tag and somewhere in body) and the script is as well (with older & recent jquery / before )

any ideas?
thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if($('classA').attr('id') == 'idB') 
{
$('idC').addClass('classD');
} 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to illustrate the exact situation a bit better?

Comment: Could you also show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: yep, i tried not just these as well: [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/30586451) [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27947009) [link](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8266662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.` before class and `#` before ID in selectors.

You can create a single selector that searches for both class and ID: `#idB.classA`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#idB.classA').length > 0) {
    $('#idC').addClass('classD');
  }
});
```

Comment: great, that works and now i feel stupid. BUT, once i scroll away and .classA gets removed, classD doesn't. Is there a way to keep checking?
Thank you!

Comment: Put the code in an event listener that runs when the actions you care about happen.

Comment: Or just write a single function that updates all the classes at once.

Comment: okay. i got the event listener somehow to do the initial request but still doesn't remove the class afterwards. as said - any efficient search terms would be sufficient. thanks again, Barmar!

Comment: Add `else {$("#idC").removeClass('classD');}`

Comment: thanks again! I don't want to annoy you, but its still keeping it although logically it shouldn't. trying further

Comment: Write a new question with the HTML and the new code, and I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks again for getting back. I called another class on the next event and with that removed the previous class. its not neat but it works. thank you for your time and have a great day!